# Download Festival UK - What should I present as an invitation letter for a UK Visa from India?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, applications, invitation-letters

I will be traveling to UK in June 19 for Download Festival in Donnington. I need to start the Visa procedure for it as soon as possible. I read in an article that I will need to present an invitation letter from UK for the Visa along with other documents. I don't think the ticket for the concert will come anytime before March, and I do not want to risk waiting till then.

How can I apply for a Visa for the above from India? What do I need to present as in invitation letter?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The earliest you can apply for a UK visitor visa is 3 months before you travel. So for a June trip, you cannot apply sooner than March.

Comment: If you are not performing at the festival but are simply attending it, you would be considered a "tourist" and will not require an invitation letter. Standard visitor visas are used for variety of purposes and as your purpose will be "leisure" all you need is a well defined itinerary (festival tickets will help), strong ties to your home country and means to support yourself.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That is good information. Thank you, my anxiety settled a bit now!

Comment: @RedBaron Understood, thank you. I will check on the festival tickets arrival dates, although I have heard they arrive quite close to the festival date. Should the itinerary include flight tickets too? Also, what does 'strong ties to my home country mean'?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde As per [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa) you don't need to provide flight bookings. But fixing your dates (and sticking to it will help). `Strong ties to home country` means that you should be able to demonstrate that you have compelling reasons to be back home after visa expires. This includes (but is not limited to) a good, stable job, family ties, property etc. We have a lot of UK visa refusal questions here. I would encourage you to take a look at those.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Download https://downloadfestival.co.uk/info/ is a 3 day festival, staying onsite it might stretch to 5 days. Depending on your travel history and personal circumstances (ties to home, job, finances etc) you should consider whether a trip from India is likely to be viewed as a strong travel premise by UKVI.

Comment: @RedBaron Aha, I have really strong ties to my home country then! I have a job, family, property etc. everything.

Comment: @Traveller I have the 3 day ticket, and my plans are around those dates only. And yes all of my life is settled here. Will try to make my case a bit more solid then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do I need to present as in invitation letter?

Present *the actual invitation letter*. If you don't have one, don't present one. It is not a compulsion.

Comment: Thanks, I think the gig tickets should suffice.