# UK visa documents

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-of-onward-travel

Is it ok to show the return ticket from another near by Schengen Country while applying for Uk visa as a proof as I haven't yet booked the internal transport yet?

Answer (score 6):

The question assumes that you need to show tickets when you apply for a visa. This is not correct.

In fact the applicant guidance [explicitly recommends not booking tickets and accommodation before you have the visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa).