# I was refused a visa..want to reapply soon cause have already pay for my ticket fee..and i dont want to make a mistake again

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

I was refused a visa to visit the UK today and i was planning in reapplying very soon cause i had already booked a ticket

The decision they made include
*i have refused your application for a visit visa because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraphs V4.2- V4.10 of appendix V because

(1) you have applied for a visa to visit the UK for 2months and 29days.you state you are a student and that a person will sponsors your visit.Although you have provided his documentation, i must also consider your own personal circumstances in Nigeria.

(2)i noted that you have not provided any documentation or information to demonstrate how you are supported financially in Nigeria .furthermore, the study documentation you provided is only a letter of offer and does not demonstrate your ongoing studies.

3. You also appear to have no dependents and you have not demonstrate that you have any assets in Nigeria or elsewhere

4.for this above reasons, i am not satisfied you have shown that, on the balance of probabilities, your ties to Nigeria or elsewhere are such that you are leaving the UK at the end of your proposed visit. I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit. Paragraph V 4.2 (a) (c) of the immigration.
    Please need someone to explain better before i reapply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) With that profile your chance of being given a visa to visit the UK is zero. Plus the application guidance specifically states you should not book your travel until you get your visa https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa

Comment: Chances are you will be refused again immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to provide additional documentation:

1) Prove that you have enough money to support yourself in Nigeria and you are not planning to stay and work illegally in the UK.

2) Prove that you have ties to Nigeria that would require you returning there (e.g. family, assets, etc)

3) Prove that you intend to study at the place for which you provided an offer letter (I am not a lawyer, but something that might help might include a receipt of payment of tuition, if this is a postsecondary institution for which tuition is an applicable concept).

You may want to ry visiting the UK consulate directly, or calling them on the phone, to try to figure out exactly what it is that they require.

Comment: The refusal the OP received is pretty standard, of which there are many examples on TSE hence the question being marked as a duplicate. Detailed guidance on UK visit visa applications is available here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/793361/Visit-guidance-v8.0ext.pdf and it’s unlikely the consulate would provide more specific advice on individual cases.

Comment: 1.does it mean my bank statement, 2.does it also mean letter of consent from my parent and a letter from my school when am to arrive and return..3.i dont really understand the dependent part..and what document should be required from my dependent(family)