# Bank loan to use as proof of funds for uk visa application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Me and my wife got refused our visa application for lack of evidence from which the others we have acquired but our big one is we didn't provide bank statements because the tls checklist stated a bank letter or statements so no proof of funds. And we are still saving.

My question is can I use bank loan as proof funds or is that not going to help? Is going be seen as funds parking? Please any advice will be appreciated as it my wife's brothers wedding and I don't want my wife to miss it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 10):

The reason why "funds parking" is a problem in the first place is that they don't want to give visas to people who can only afford to travel by borrowing money!

The reasoning is that since no responsible person would go into debt for a pleasure trip, something else must be up -- probably the applicant is considering the cost of travel to be an investment and hopes to find illegal work in the UK so he can send money home to pay off the loan. (Whether this reasoning is *reasonable* or not is a question that does not really belong here; the fact is that it is the reasoning visa authorities follow).

Since your claim is not merely that you're going on a random tourist trip, but attending a close relative's wedding, there ought to be a slightly larger chance that you can convince the ECO that it makes sense for you to travel for borrowed money. But even so you will still need to convince them that your economy is such that you can expect to be able to pay off the loan in a reasonable time after the trip.

For this you **need** bank statements, and an income with a reliable surplus to save or make loan payments from.

See our canonical explanation at [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there anything that can show we can afford the repayments, or add a letter stating that we want to go for the wedding. The problem is most of our funds went for booking the tickets and booking accommodation. Will they take this in consideration or not at all. What happens if they flag an individual what are consequences of this?

Comment: @Predator1987: The UK officially recommends _not_ to pay for tickets and accommodation until you know you have a visa. If you have done so anyway, then of course you don't need to have money ready to do it once again -- but you still need to show bank statements do document your income and ordinary expenses. Please read the question I linked to in at the end of the answer!

Comment: Hi Henning. I think I understand. They want to see more in and out cash flow that I have a job etc. So in taking a loan and having a job will show connections to the economy. The reason we bought the tickets is that the travel agent we will need these for the visa application. I really appreciate your help and appologize for all the questions. Because we are considering cancelling becuase we might get refused again and it will hurt future applications so we are stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: @Predator1987: (1) Don't let anyone who claims the UK still requires flight/hotel bookings anywhere near your visa applications. (See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa) for sources). (2) I don't think taking out a loan will count as a particular connection to the economy. Having a steady income from a job certainly will.

Comment: Thank you Henning I read through everything so far. Flights and bookings don't help. The main thing we are worried about is us being flagged if it gets denied a second time what consequences does this have for an individual applying for a visa?

Comment: @Predator1987: Not all refusals are created equal. Some people keep applying with different stories each time in the hope that one of them will be good enough. They soon find themselves in a hole of lost credibility that it is impossible to climb out from. But if I understand you correctly, _your_ refusal was a matter of missing bank statements that you _could_ have provided. If you apply again _without changing your story_ but with the documentation for it that was missing the first time, I don't think that will count against you.

Comment: There is a lot more patience for "the same application, but now done right" than there is for "spin the wheel another time" applications.

Comment: Thank you Henning all the help and advice is greatly appreciated.