# Partial accommodation evidence for UK standard visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Indian citizen applying for UK standard visitor visa.

I have booked onward ticket from my place to London on 2nd July, return ticket from London on 17th July.

I have accommodation from 7th July to 13th July.

I did not yet booked accommodation for remaining days.  There is still some confusion where I would be going in these remaining days which is unlikely to get settle before my visa interview (22/May/2019).

Does that create a problem?

Comment: The applicant guidance for the UK _explicitly recommends_ NOT to book flights or accommodation until you know you have a visa.

Comment: :D :D Ok.. So,  visa officer might not have any problem for me not having  **accommodation** evidence... Should I mention this to the officer? @HenningMakholm

Comment: See section 4 of [this document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) and [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa) for some discussion.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh... Thanks thanks.. I have seen that just now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the UK mentions not booking flights and not making reservation for hotels till the visa is awarded, the officer who interviews you will not have problems with you not having bookings for those days.
They may ask for plans but will understand if you do not yet have detailed plans for those days.

Already having tickets and reservations may prove to be a bigger problem as it shows you did not read the instructions. The main risk there is that you may lose a lot of money if your visa is not approved.