# UK tourist visa - Different PNRs in same flight for me and Spouse. Both of us should submit both tickets for visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

Me and my wife are applying for UK tourist visa. We have different PNRs for same flight on same day for onward journey. In return journey it is same PNR. When we will provide flight details proof for individual applications, should we both include both own and spouse ticket copy of onward journey?

[image]

Comment: UKVI specifically states that travel reservations are not required when submitting a visitor visa application - see section 4 of https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: I suggest asking the question about the marriage certificate as a separate question, with its own title, so it will get proper attention.

Comment: Thanks @Traveller. Yes I read that but then in doc checklist given after application submission has flight and acco details as examples under 'tour details' category. I understand that they are not mandatory but since I have already booked, I wish to provide.

Comment: Do you see this on the official UK web site, or at VFS Global?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the UK ask for travel bookings for a tourist visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/why-doesnt-the-uk-ask-for-travel-bookings-for-a-tourist-visitor-visa). If you want to ignore the official UKVI guidance and include them anyway, you don’t need to duplicate the documents. But as travel bookings are not required, providing them is unlikely to have any effect on the ECO’s decision and it’s probable they won’t even be examined.

Comment: Hello Michael, I have edited my post to include image where doc checklist generated on completion of application on gov.uk mentions tour details, which has flight details as a suggestion.

Comment: "Flight details" is something quite different from "flight bookings". They're interested in your planned itinerary, but they specifically don't want you to book anything before getting the visa. They literally say you "should not send bookings unless specifically requested", which IMHO says it all. The ECO will likely just ignore these superfluous documents, perhaps thinking "yet another guy who can't read the rules".

Comment: Please explain what is the difference in "flight details" and "flight bookings" and how will I have flight details without flight bookings. If they are interested in itinerary, they get in application form.  I think you are the one here who can't read the text in image I posted above, so don't act smart. I very well know they don't ask for bookings during application, so later on asking flight details in checklist is just something which leads to confusion.